# How can I split SQL Server columns from one table into separate tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with columns `A, B, C, D,` and `E`.

I would like to split the table but maintain relationships between tables.

Is there a simple way to make table `ABCDE` into 2 tables `uABC` and `uDE` and throw in a unique identifier that connects rows across tables? The end goal is to build a one-to-many relationship and remove duplicated data.

Comment: I think this depends on the data that is being duplicated. Which is the one? Which is the many?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the most duplication happens in the ABC part:

```
CREATE TABLE ABC
(
 id [int] PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
 A  [datatype],
 B  [datatype],
 C  [datatype], 
)
GO

CREATE TABLE DE
(
 id [int] PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
 D  [datatype],
 E  [datatype],
 ABC_id [int] NOT NULL REFERENCES ABC(id)
)
GO

INSERT INTO ABC (A, B, C)
SELECT DISTINCT A, B, C
FROM ABCDE
GO

INSERT INTO DE(D,E,ABC_id)
SELECT DISTINCT D,E, ABC.id
FROM ABC
JOIN ABCDE
ON ABC.A = ABCDE.A
AND ABC.B = ABCDE.B
AND ABC.C = ABCDE.C
GO
```

Comment: Great stuff! This is exactly what I needed.  I just adjusted it a bit to meet my variable names and types!  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE uABC
(
 u  [datatype],
 A  [datatype],
 B  [datatype],
 C  [datatype], 
)
GO

CREATE TABLE uDE
(
 u  [datatype],
 D  [datatype],
 E  [datatype], 
)
GO

INSERT INTO uABC (u, A, B, C)
SELECT u, A, B, C
FROM  uABCDE
GO

INSERT INTO uDE(u,D,E)
SELECT u,D,E
FROM  uABCDE
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's a Primary Key on that table already, you can just put the primary key on both tables.

If column A is the primary key... then

```
`Table1`
A, B, C
```

and

```
`Table2`
A, D, E
```

Or, you can add a surrogate key on the table to create the relationship.